# C++ can a user use cin to create a new string?

Tags: c++

I made a dictionary. My goal is to have the user enter new words and define them.

I think I have the 'define words' part down, and I have the rest down. I wrote an example of kinda what I am looking for below. I don't want someone to do it for me; I just want to know if there is a way to do this and where I could learn more.

Right now, I am using C++ for Dummies and Sam's Teach Yourself For Teachers.

```
string newword
string word

cout << "Please enter a word" >> endl;
cin >> word;
if (word == newword)
{
    create string <newword>; // Which would make the following
                             // source code appear without
                             // actually typing anything new
                             // into the source code.
}  
string newword
string word
string word2 // which would make this happen

cout << "Please enter a word" >> endl;
cin >> word;
if (word == newword)
{
    create string <newword> 
}
```

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you are asking for here.

Comment: @EdS.: He's looking for an array.  Except he's really looking for a `vector`, because they're better than arrays.

Comment: Also, it's `std::cout << "string" << std::endl;` not `std::cout << "string" >> std::endl;`

Answer (score 3):

I would use `std::map` since, well, it's a dictionary style container. The `map` container is perfect for this situation, and you can provide **unique keys** to match with other data. Since a typical dictionary only has **one entry** for each word, this is perfect.

A typedef allow us to define a type with a name. It is helpful here here as we don't have to type `std::map<std::string, std::string>` over and over. Imagine each time you see `Dictionary`, it is replace with `std::map<std::string, std::string>`

```
// Map template requires 2 types, Key type and Value type.
// In our case, they are both strings.
typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> Dictionary;
Dictionary myDict;
```

Then I would ask the user for entries, and then ask them to define their entries.

```
std::string word;
std::cout << "What word would you like added to the dictionary?" << std::endl;
std::cin >> word;

std::string definition;
std::cout << "Please define the word " << word << std::endl;
std::cin >> definitiion;
```

Next step would simply insert the word and it's definition into the dictionary. Using the `[]` operator on a map, we replace any entry that already exists for the supplied key `word`. If it doesn't exist already, it will be inserted as a new entry. Note that any previously defined word of the same name will now have a new definition!

```
myDict[word] = definition;
```

Running this would produce something similar to:

```
>> What word would you like added to the dictionary?
>> Map
>> Please define the word Map
>> Helps you find things
```

Accessing definitions in the map is now trivial:

```
myDict["Map"]; // Retrieves the string "Helps you find things"
```

Comment: This is a much better way to solve the stated problem than mine because it enables definitions to be attached to words.  But from the way the question is written, it might be helpful to explain in more detail what each step (e.g. `typedef`) does.

Comment: +1 for a sane, easy to understand answer.  Nit pick though: I hate seeing std::cin >> x where success isn't checked for, and recommend using if (std::cin >> x) ... else std::cerr << "unable to read x from stdin\n"; or similar.

Comment: @TonyDelroy - Thankyou and agreed. However I'm also not checking for `" "` entries, capitalization, nor performing any other sanitization on the input. This answers highlights the use of `std::map`, and uses `iostream` as a consequence. The user should definitely take your comment into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** My answer only shows you how to build a list of words without definitions.  Hopefully it will open some mental doors, but to accomplish your main goal of attaching a definition to each word, you'll want to use a `map` instead of a `vector`, as [Aesthete's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12487818/47984) shows.

What you need is a variable containing a *collection* of strings.  One of the easiest to use, and most commonly used, is a vector:

```
// At the top of your program
#include <vector>

...

vector<string> words;

...

cout << "Please enter a word" << endl;
cin >> word;
words.push_back(word);     // This adds word to the end of the vector.
```

A vector behaves very much like an array in that if you have a vector called `words`, you can access the (i+1)th element using the syntax `words[i]`:

```
cout << "The 3rd word is " << words[2] << endl;
```

You can replace the `2` above with some other more complicated expression, including one that depends on variables.  That allows you to do things like list all the words.

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i) {
    cout << "Word " << (i + 1) << " is " << words[i] << endl;
}
```

etc.

Comment: For a dictionary it would be best to use a map, not a vector.

Comment: @EdS.: Certainly, but it looks like he's only at the stage of adding words without definitions so far and perhaps isn't familiar even with arrays.  Need to walk before you run!

Comment: *"My goal is to have the user enter new words and define them."*, but I see your point

Comment: thanks everyone who gave input the std::map was helpful to know about